# Is it possible to use one ValueAnimator or ObjectAnimator to animate multiple values in a Matrix?

Tags: android

I'm trying to change the X and Y scales of a Matrix object in conjunction with the changing shape of an ImageView to make it seem like the ImageView is merely a mask.

So in order to do that, I would change the scale of the ImageView's Matrix to reciprocate the changing scale of the ImageView itself.

So far, I'm using a single ValueAnimator to change the X scale of the Matrix and it worked:

```
final ValueAnimator xScaleIterationMatrix = ValueAnimator.ofFloat((1/xScaleSrcToDst)*initMatDstVals[0], initMatDstVals[0]);
                                    final Matrix mat = initMatrixDst;
xScaleIterationMatrix.setDuration(animDurationCommon);
xScaleIterationMatrix.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
        mat.setScale((float)xScaleIterationMatrix.getAnimatedValue(), initMatDstVals[4]);
        toReplace.interfaceImageView().setImageMatrix(mat);
        }
    });
xScaleIterationMatrix.start();
```

But that's just one ValueAnimator, and only one property (scaleX) of the Matrix.

I was thinking of using 2 ValueAnimators (to change the scaleX and scaleY [while setting the matrix in the latter]) to do that, but I wish for something simpler.

Can I use an ObjectAnimator for this task?

EDIT: The sample code for the 2 ValueAnimators proposal:

```
final ValueAnimator xScaleIterationMatrix = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(xScaleSrcToDst * initMatSrcVals[0], initMatSrcVals[0]);
xScaleIterationMatrix.setDuration(animDurationCommon);
xScaleIterationMatrix.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
        resultXScale = (float)xScaleIterationMatrix.getAnimatedValue();
        }
    });
xScaleIterationMatrix.start();

final ValueAnimator yScaleIterationMatrix = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(yScaleSrcToDst * initMatSrcVals[4], initMatSrcVals[4]);
yScaleIterationMatrix.setDuration(animDurationCommon);
yScaleIterationMatrix.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
        resultYScale = (float)yScaleIterationMatrix.getAnimatedValue();
        mat.setScale(resultXScale, resultYScale);
        source.interfaceImageView().setImageMatrix(mat);
        }
    });
yScaleIterationMatrix.start();
```

Comment: I would guess you might be able to write a custom TypeEvaluator and have it do the translation. I'm not an expert with Android though. Studying